# context.font = "...px Font Name"

Tags: javascript, font-size

Lets take:

context.font = "80px Georgia";

What I want is a way replaces the 80px with (window.innerWidth-window.innerHeight) or something else so that the size of your font adjusts to the size of your window height/length...

Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [relative unit](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) (like %) or [calc](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) without any JavaScript.

Comment: I need to do it with js, becaue it's for drawings in canvas,  like this....->>>>>                                                        context.font = "80px Georgia";
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.fillText = ("...."):